# Reference Request: Cuspidal Representations from Irreducible Representations

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I am reading a paper in which the following statement is given.

"Let $\rho:S_3\to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the irreducible two-dimensional representation. Then $\rho$ gives rise to a cuspidal representation $\pi$ of $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$"

Here, $S_3$ is the symmetric group on three symbols and $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$ is the ring of adeles of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know the relelvant definitions in the statement, but I do not know how this construction is done. Any reference to this would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You can construct it via _automorphic induction_, so learn about that.

Comment: I know the notion of an induced representation. Does this have to do something with that? If so, can you provide some more details?

Comment: It is analogue of induction of Galois representations for automorphic representations.  There are various surveys that discuss this, though I don't have a particular recommendation (maybe it's in Gelbart's Bulletin article, I'm pretty sure Cogdell's lecture notes touch on this).  The most classical case is CM modular forms, so you could start by learning about that.  By the way, you probably want $\rho$ to be a representation of a Galois group, not abstract $S_3$, because this will tell you what quadratic field to induce from.

Comment: Yes yes, absolutely. The group S3 is actually a Galois group of a degree six extension of Q